# Android SDK - warnings in Hello World

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings

being new to the Android SDK (but not Java), I have a probably trivial question about warnings in the Hello World app. I realize warnings aren't errors, but I like my logs clean and warnings are typically there for a reason.

First off, there is a line in the `HelloWorldActivity` saying:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

However, the validator complains that "*The resource R.layout.main appears to be unused"* in Line 1 of `main.xml`. Why is this the case? Can I get rid of it?

Secondly, the project in Eclipse came with three folders named drawable-Xdpi, where X is l, m or h. The validator shows a warning *"Missing density variation folders in res: drawable-xhdpi*". I assumed my Eclipse version was old, added a new drawable folder similar to the others and created an icon of the appropriate size 96x96. However, the warning still appears as if the new drawable folder is not there. Did I forget something?

I have searched for others with the same problem, found some, but no solution was given. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: Did you put the drawable inside the "res" folder

Comment: Cleaning was a nice idea, but didn't have any effect. The folder (both on disk and in the eclipse project) is structured /res/drawable-xhdpi/ and contains a single file ic_launcher.png, just like the other folders.

Comment: I manually deleted the warnings, and they did not reappear. Apparently, there's a bug where old warnings stick even though they are no longer valid. Solved, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the R.java file under the gen folder.  Some Eclipse versions always show this error, and when you recomplile, it auto-creates a new one.  It worked for me.